# sum sql group by values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've got 2 tables: Online Orders, Online orders details
I have an issue on how to calculate the total amount of the order in Online Order table based on the detail order table.

The detail table looks like:

```
id_order    Id_product  quantity    price   value
1                2         1           3      3
1                3         2           2      4
2                1         1           5      5
```

I would like to sum all the values from an id_order and insert them into the total amount of the order in the Online orders table.

Can you help me with the SQL command?

Comment: Which one is it? MySQL? SQL Server? Plain SQL?

Comment: I guess you fell for a really bad Chinese copy. There's no such thing as MySQL Server 2005. You can either have MySQL or SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what database system you use.
If you want to UPDATE `orders.total_amount` 
This update statement will work under any DB:

```
update orders 
  set total_amount = (
               select SUM(value)
                 from orders_details
                where id_order = orders.id
              )
   where EXISTS(select *
                 from orders_details
                where id_order = orders.id)
```

This update statement works under MySQL:

```
update orders u
inner join (select id_order, SUM(value) as total
                     from orders_details
                    GROUP BY  id_order) s on
    u.id = s.id_order
set u.total_amoun = s.total
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT o.id_order, SUM(quantity * price) AS total_price
FROM online o
     INNER JOIN detail d
         ON d.id_order = o.id_order
GROUP BY o.id_order
```

Comment: That should be it. Thank you!

Comment: @user3328253 I'm selecting form `online` first just to filter rows, but you could also select from `detail` only and have a `WHERE EXISTS` or `WHERE id_order IN (...)` clause.